# Tips on making a YouTube channel

Tags: youtube

I had the idea of starting a YouTube channel (called 'Hardcore Durability Test') focused on creating entertaining durability tests on all sorts of items. The show would be presented by two children (one 13 and the other 11) who are actually much more sensible than their ages suggest. Does anyone have any general tips on making this? Thanks!

Comment: You need to be way more specific. What sort of advice are you after?

Comment: Mainly about how to gain popularity and optimise video content to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extremely broad question, but I'll do my best to provide a quick surface overview.  Producing good quality video is HARD.  To put it in perspective, I'm working on an indie level web series right now and I'd guess it takes probably around 10 man hours of work per minute of video.  Making a successful video involves lots of planning and high quality execution, all of which takes time and a variety of different skills.

You start out with writing.  The concept of the show needs to be flushed out.  Improv is an option, but the basic premise still needs to be there and the topics, items to test, etc all need to be determined in a way that gives the foundation for producing content that holds together and is interesting to viewers.

Then you need to begin producing the video.  This involves gathering and organizing the resources you will need to make the video.  You will need products to test, your cast is already selected, but you'll need crew (possibly yourself for now) and equipment that can be used for actual production.

Once everything you need for production is gathered, you have to actually execute the production.  This involves making sure you have good sets, lighting, sound, video, etc.  You need to make sure that the video both looks and sounds good and that there is good content in the raw footage you shoot.

Next, you move in to post production once all the footage is shot.  This is when you work on editing the footage in to the final consumable form.  You have to work out pacing of the content and add any post production elements like titles and graphics and any additional sounds in order to make sure that the final product is interesting to watch.

Finally, you move in to release and marketing.  In this case, you've already decided that you want to release on Youtube, but just putting a video up on Youtube isn't going to get people to watch it quickly.  You need to let people know about the video and raise awareness about it.  This can be as simple as making social media posts about the videos to your various networks or as complicated as actual paid advertising to reach out beyond your direct network.  You might also consider trying to get news coverage of the show for some free marketing if you can get any news sources to pick up the story.

As an added bonus, there is also the luck factor.  Even if you do everything completely wrong, there is a large luck factor in any release, especially on places like Youtube.  Certainly well maintained and high production value channels tend to have the most staying power, but just about any video has the possibility of going viral regardless of almost any other factors if the stars align just right.  Even if you do everything right, there is still no guarantee of success.  It's notoriously hard to tell what people will or won't find interesting and even major large budget projects fall victim to this.  It comes down to how things strike people's fancy and people are fickle.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube is the answer to YouTube. There are plenty of Videos on how-to everything.

You can see other people's Format (and comments) so you don't copy the bad ideas or compete with a far better Channel.

From learning what is current and what other people have done, to finding out which Camera is recommended (and what Settings / Bitrate / Format). It's all there.

10's of thousands of hours of lessons.